# Connection Error while trying to create SQL DB connection from nodejs

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server-2005

While trying to connect SQL DB from a NodeJs class, I am getting an error:

> ConnectionError: Connection not yet open

```
var sql = require("mssql");
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var executeQuery = function(res, query) { 

var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);

conn.connect()
     .then(function (pool) {

         // create Request object
         var request = new sql.Request(pool);                          
         // query to the database
         request.query(query, function (err, queryResult) {
             if (err) {
                 console.log(err);
                 res.send(err);
             } else {
                 res.send(queryResult);
             }
         });
         conn.close();
    });           
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing the connection before request.query is processed as this is an async call. Move conn.close() inside the callback for request.query.

```
var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);

conn.connect()
     .then(function (pool) {

         // create Request object
         var request = new sql.Request(pool);                          
         // query to the database
         request.query(query, function (err, queryResult) {
             if (err) {
                 console.log(err);
                 res.send(err);
             } else {
                 res.send(queryResult);
             }
             conn.close();
         });
    });           
}
```